# SQL timeout for no reason

Tags: sql-server, azure, tcp

I host an azure appservice and sometimes it gets random timeouts on queries that usually take 1ms to complete. The SQL server is hosted in azure too and they talk to each other in a private network. What could be going wrong. It even happens when there is no load and I do one call. 99% of the calls work but it's the 1% that happens way to frequently. It's causing 40 second timeouts for no reason.

There are almost zero open connections. The database is 1200 DTU. The appservice is p3v2 and has always on. Performance to the database seem to be really good except if a query randomly takes really long. It almost seems like there is a connection issue in the azure backbone. It seems to happen almost once every 40 database requests. The transient error rate is higher than I have ever seen on any application. We never hit above 20% DTU but the errors still happen around 1% DTU. It randomly started happening two weeks ago after maintenance from Microsoft. We did not deploy new code during that time.

The exception I see is:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.) A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Comment: Likely transient errors. Have you implemented a retry strategy? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/troubleshoot-common-connectivity-issues?view=azuresql

Comment: @CSharpRocks These transient errors seem to happen 1 in 40 calls and take over 40 seconds. Is that really what should be happening ? In other applications I have never seen anything like this.

Comment: Do you have a database shutdown timer? Have you checked for poor DNS, poor network conenctions? Are you disposing/closing all your connections properly (and therefore reusing them via connection pooling) otherwise you may get socket exhaustion, and/or overload the server.

Comment: @Joey, 1 out of 40 seems high in your case with a premium app plan and that much DTU. I would file a support case to have someone look in to your specific environment. And as a side note I would also plan to go from DTU purchasing model to a vCore purchasing model that makes much more sense and which provide much more transparence and understanding. Noone really gets what DTU is :-)

Comment: We are in contact with microsoft but there is still no fix. At this point something is broken in de backbone of microsoft. So its quite unlucky that we are experiencing this.

Answer (score 0):

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.)

From [Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/connect/network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-connection),

***Cause:***

The SQL Server client is unable to reach the server. The server's firewall may have rejected the connection or the server may not be set up to accept remote connections, which might both lead to this error.

***Workaround:***

Ensure that the firewall on the machine is set up to let this instance of SQL Server to receive connections and to enable remote connections for SQL Server, use the SQL Server Configuration Manager tool.